# Parameters not passed to controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, model, controller

I am trying the following code for getting subcategory from the category field that I was selected using ajax. But the value is not passed to the controller function. I tried every solution and but still does not work.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "echo base_url().'design/get_sub_category';",
  traditional: true,
  data: JSON.stringify(id),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you probably want this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/design/get_sub_category",
  traditional: true,
  data: JSON.stringify(id),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
```

`base_url()` is a PHP function and you need to echo the output as `<?php echo base_url() ?>`.